# jQuery POST an object like this

Tags: jquery, django, post

How can I send this field using jquery's POST

```
"geo": {
        "coordinates": [
              56.3561,
              25.3392
        ],
        "type": "Point"
}
```

...

```
data: {geo:{"coordinates": [56.3561,25.3392],"type": "Point"}}
```

results in `String or unicode input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB`

Comment: whether you want to sent the data as request body or as a param value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert that JSON object to serliazed string first.

```
var jsonObject = {"geo": {
    "coordinates": [
          56.3561,
          25.3392
    ],
    "type": "Point"
}}
```

and then :

```
data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: if this solved your problem, please accept it as answer.